# Why don't listbox assigns to gridview ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, count, listbox

I have filled listBox with data and assigning it to gridview but it doesn't. I verified by setting count of list to variable and it shows 3, perfect but after assigning it to gridview, the count of gridview shows 0. Why ?

```
 protected void btnShowTempFeatures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = ListBoxFeatures.Items.Count; //returns 3
            grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataSource = ListBoxFeatures.DataSource;
            grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataBind();

            int CountGrid= grdViewTemporaryFeatures.Rows.Count; //return 0


                    }

}
```

Comment: No you can't just do `grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataSource = ListBoxFeatures.DataSource;`. You need to assign the actual data source.

Comment: i removed datasource from it and still no luck

Comment: I assume you are trying to populate `grdViewTemporaryFeatures` with items in `ListBoxFeatures`. Does your `ListBoxFeatures` have items? If yes, how are you binding `ListBoxFeatures`?

Comment: yes it does have items

Comment: done and i posted solution . thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
   protected void btnShowTempFeatures_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int count = ListBoxFeatures.Items.Count;
            //grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataSource = ListBoxFeatures.DataSource;
            //grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataBind();

            int CountGrid= grdViewTemporaryFeatures.Rows.Count;

            ListItemCollection lstTempFeatures = ListBoxFeatures.Items;

            DataTable dTempFeatures = new DataTable();
            dTempFeatures.Columns.Add("ID");
            dTempFeatures.Columns.Add("FeatureName");

            foreach (ListItem lstItem in lstTempFeatures) 
            {
                DataRow dr = dTempFeatures.NewRow();
                dr["ID"]= lstItem.Value;
                dr["FeatureName"] = lstItem.Text;

                dTempFeatures.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataSource = dTempFeatures;
            grdViewTemporaryFeatures.DataBind();

            mdlTemporaryFeatures.Show();
        }
```